# sum for a specific rows in a specific column: Pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I do have an excel sheet which has a values of watts represent the hourly electricity consumption of different houses. 
I wanna sum a specific group of rows in a specific column then plot it.

so far I have imported the excel file and I could plot a whole column by coding the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

start_date = "2017-07-24 00:00:00"
end_date = "2019-03-09 23:00:00"

data_generation2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Master\\Thesis\\Tarek\\Parent.xlsx", index_col="Timestamp")

data_consumption2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Master\\Thesis\\Tarek\\Parent.xlsx", index_col="Timestamp", sheetname="Consumption")

data_generation = data_generation2.loc[start_date:end_date] 
data_consumption = data_consumption2.loc[start_date:end_date] 
time= data_consumption2.iloc[:,0]
fifthcol= data_consumption2.iloc[:,5]
plt.xticks(np.arange(2017))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 4000, 500))
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("consumption")
plt.plot(time,fifthcol,label="total consumption(2017,2018)")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

no error messages but I need to know the statements that can sum the first x rows in the y column

Comment: As a suggestion to make your question clearer, provide a toy example and the result you want to get.

Comment: for example, I have a column that represents the month salaries and I wanna calculate the average salary in summer then I need to extract the 6th 7th and the 8th rows and sum the values and divide it on 3 to get the average salary

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your favorite column is

```
c = data_consumption.consumption
```

and you wish to focus on the 6th through 8th rows.
Use `c[6:9].sum()`, or `sum(c[6:9])`, as you prefer.

(Equivalently, you might assign `c = data_consumption['consumption']`.)